# Can I overwrite a css class in a UserControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have this context:

```
<asp:Panel ID="DescrizionePagina" CssClass="pagina-testo-box-large" runat="server">Text</asp:Panel>
```

and I'd like to overwrite the class with `pagina-testo-box-small`:

```
Panel myPanel = (Panel)this.Parent.FindControl("DescrizionePagina");
myPanel.Attributes.Add("class", "pagina-testo-box-small");
```

but it doesnt works... `pagina-testo-box-large` remains...

Comment: _"Can I overwrite a class in a UserControl?"_ The title is out of context, you have not shown your `UserControl`. Where is the `Panel`, where the `UserControl` (in the page)?

Comment: Why do you need to use `FindControl` at all?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: why not? It is in another control...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you already know the [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx), why don't you use it?

```
Panel myPanel = (Panel)this.Parent.FindControl("DescrizionePagina");
myPanel.CssClass = "pagina-testo-box-small";
```

Comment: @timSchmelter is there any difference between these two?

Comment: The property `CssClass`, if set, will take precedence and overwrite the `Attributes["class"]`. I assume that `.Attributes.Add` will add it only if it doesn't already exist, hence it will do nothing above. He could also try to use `Attributes[class]="pagina-testo-box-small"`. But then you have to check if it exists first to prevent an exception. As you see, using `CssClass` is better.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `CssClass` property -- the same that you already set in your ASPX code:

```
myPanel.CssClass = "pagina-testo-box-small";
```

Behind the scenes, the .NET property `CssClass` will be translated to the HTML `class` attribute, but ASP.NET takes care of this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
myPanel.CssClass = "pagina-testo-box-small";
```

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn't work as suggest in the above answers

```
Panel myPanel = (Panel)this.Parent.FindControl("DescrizionePagina");
myPanel.CssClass = "pagina-testo-box-small";
```

Then you can use like this for individual attribute use `!important`

```
 Panel myPanel = (Panel)this.Parent.FindControl("DescrizionePagina");
 myPanel.Style.Add("float", "left!important");
```